# Apache TinkerPop Gremlin Vertex Equality

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

While traversing a graph, I'd like to save the starting vertex, traverse a little further, and remove any vertices that have a specific edge back to this saved vertex.

This is my current attempt, but it obviously is not correct:

```
g.V().hasLabel('foo')
  .as('rule')
.repeat(out('belongs_to')).times(2)
.where(
  in('accepts').is(neq('rule'))
)
```

How can I check for vertex equality in Gremlin? How do I filter out all paths where such an equality exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where()` matches the start- and end-label, thus you can use `where(in('accepts').as('rule'))`. And since you want to exclude those vertices that match the pattern, you need to negate this part using `not()`.

```
g.V().hasLabel('foo').as('rule').
  repeat(out('belongs_to')).
    times(2).
  not(where(__.in('accepts').as('rule')))
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! What if there are many `accepts` edges from this vertex. I want to exclude any paths involving this vertex if _any_ of these `accepts` edges lands back at the starting vertex.

I think this solution will only prune the paths that have this edge, and not the parent vertex, right? In any case, this is what my original question asked for, but I'd appreciate any more clarification you could offer!

Comment: So if any vertex along the path has an `accepts` edge that goes back to the initial vertex, you want to exclude it? In that case, you would just move the whole `not(...)` filter step into the `repeat()` step.

Comment: This is **exquisitely** non-obvious, and this solved something I'd been stuck on for a full day. Thanks!